# ImportScripts() web worker scope of variables

Tags: javascript, web-worker

Does this code

```
if (typeof importScripts === 'function') {

importScripts('somelib.js');

}

//some code between

if (typeof importScripts === 'function') {
    var i = some_function_from_imported_lib(params);
//CODE CODE CODE
}
```

is the same as

```
if (typeof importScripts === 'function') {

importScripts('somelib.js');
    var i = some_function_from_imported_lib(params);
//CODE CODE CODE
}
```

?

In other words, does it matter `importScripts()` is wrapped by some parenthesises or not? Does it matter for scope of functions and variables inside `somelib.js`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That completely depends on:

```
//some code between
```

If that "some" code doesn't have *any* effect on the imported lib's functions, or your parameters, then:

```
if (typeof importScripts === 'function') {
    importScripts('somelib.js');
}
//some code between
if (typeof importScripts === 'function') {
    var i = some_function_from_imported_lib(params);
}
```

Is functionally the same as:

```
if (typeof importScripts === 'function') {
    importScripts('somelib.js');
    var i = some_function_from_imported_lib(params);
}
```

Those `if` blocks don't have their own scope.